# android wear application not installing immediately

Tags: android, wear-os

I am developing mobile multidex application which has wear support.When I install signed apk to mobile,it works but takes a lot of time to deploy on my huawei watch. **I do not know the root cause of delay.**. Has anyone come across the same situation?I already factory reset both my handset and my watch.Thanks for any help or clue.

Comment: When I do the same (install mobile application pair to emulator wear, it is so fast deployed to emulator wear) either from apk (with adb command) or from playstore. I think the problem is transfer rate bluetooth in real android wear slower than usb connection to emulator wear. CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

Finally I downgrade playservice library to 8.4, I do not know why if I choose 9.4 or >9.0 not deployed wearable application to my Huawei watch